# Decovolutional layer not match the original layer

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to apply FPN to my network.
Here I have a 48*27 layer, after conv layer, it comes to 24*14, but after deconvolutional layer, it becomes 48*28, not the same as 48*27. So these layers could not do add/mul op.

How can I fix this problem? I am use TensorFlow and 'SAME' padding way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a convolution with 'SAME' padding and a stride of 2 will have an output shape of 24*14 for all the following input shapes:

48*27, 48*28, 47*27 and 47*28

Therefore `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` can not know the correct output shape by itself and it goes with the symmetric case of doubling each of the dimensions: 24*14 -> 48*28

If you want to use a different output shape you can use the [lower level deconvolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose): `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`

Using it allows you to specify the output shape.

Alternatively you can adjust your whole network such that the input shape is always a multiple of the stride. Then the deconvolution will always predict the correct output shape.